# Make columns into row subgroups in Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a basic table - list of locations, x types of trees, with the value being the number of trees planted in each location.

| Location | Tree 1 | Tree 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | 456 |
| B | 789 | 012 |

What I want is for the locations and trees to be in the same column and the values in a second column.

| Location | Number |
| --- | --- |
| Loc. A |  |
| ---Tree 1 | 123 |
| ---Tree 2 | 456 |
| Loc. B |  |
| ---Tree 1 | 789 |
| ---Tree 2 | 012 |

Comment: In Power Query, you can use Unpivot Columns to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Power Query to unpivot your existing data.  Then save it as a Pivot Table Report, and enter the Location and Tree as Rows, and the Numbers as Values

If you make changes in your original data, a simple refresh of the query will refresh the Pivot table.

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range`
- Select the "Location" column (or a single cell in that column)
- `Transform => Unpivot other columns`
- Change the Column Headers to `Tree` and `Number`
- `Home => Close and Load => Pivot Table Report` (and select either a new sheet or someplace on an existing sheet
- Now just drag Location to Rows; Tree to Rows; Number to Columns
- Rename the existing columns to taste
- Under Pivot options, you can deselect to show subtotals and totals.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To do this with a PivotTable, you need to slightly tweak your data as follows:

[image: data]

Once the data is prepared, select the data -> `Insert` -> `PivotTable`.
Enter Location and Tree in the Rows field and Number in the Values field, respectively. This gives the following output (you can easily turn off the sub- and grand total if not needed):

[image: output]