# Transform list data into formatted matrix based on values using Power Query

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

### **Background**

I recently took a position at an orchard. The planting maps and other data are stored in many different files, each with different formatting and structures, maintained and created by different individuals. When a change is made in the orchard (i.e. a tree is planted, or dies) information has to be updated on several different files – which is cumbersome and extremely prone to error.

A goal of mine is to store all the planting data in one file (which only I make edits to), from which other summary files and reports can be generated automatically and distributed.
This question pertains to one style of summary file that many people at the orchard use. It is a matrix that has some spatial correlation to the layout of our orchard (e.g. the rows and columns of the worksheet correspond to cardinal directions and mimic the layout of the orchard)

### **Question**

Several supervisors at the orchard prefer to view the planting data in matrix form, where the direction of the columns and rows relate to the cardinal direction (N, E, S, W) and the layout of the orchard (see example).

How can I take this data in list form, and transform it into a matrix with specific formatting?

I have tried different combinations of  `Group By`, `Transpose`, `Unpivot Columns`, `Split Column`, `Pivot Column` with no success.

**Requirements**

I want to have one “master” worksheet that is maintained that I make edits to. There will be several other worksheets or workbooks that automatically update from my master worksheet.

1. Each value for `BlockN` will have a dedicated worksheet (Note: In this example, there is only one value for `BlockN`, in the actual dataset there are currently 13 distinct values).
2. Each distinct value for `RowN` will have a dedicated column in the output.

   - The order of the distinct values in `RowN` will be reversed (i.e. sorted left --> right from Z --> A).
   - The heading for each column will be a concatenation of the unique values of `RowN` and `RowNm`.
3. Each distinct value in the `Loc` column will have a dedicated row.
4. The value in each of the output cells with be a concatenation of `Variety` and `Planting Year`.
5. There will be conditional formatting to each cell dependent on the corresponding value for `Status`.

   - Living = Green fill
   - Dead = Red fill
   - Unplanted = Blue fill

**Preferred, but not necessarily required.**

1. Formatting within the output

   - Cardinal directions (North, East, South, West) around the borders of the output.
   - A title that is a concatenation of the distinct values for `Block` and `BlockNm`.

**Potential problems?**

1. How will this handle blanks? There are going to be some cells that are blank because nothing was planted there
2. What if there are different ranges of values for `loc`. For example `RowN A` might be “001 – 060” and `RowN B` might be “001 – 120”

### Example Source Data

| Variety | Block | BlockNm | RowN | RowNm | Loc | Planting Year | Status | RowSp | LocSp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Green | 1 | Fruit Tree | A | Short Trees | 001 | 2022 | Living | 12 | 3 |
| Red | 1 | Fruit Tree | A | Short Trees | 002 | 2020 | Living | 12 | 3 |
| Tasty | 1 | Fruit Tree | A | Short Trees | 003 | 2022 | Dead | 12 | 3 |
| Blue | 1 | Fruit Tree | A | Short Trees | 004 | 2019 | Unplanted | 12 | 3 |
| Sour | 1 | Fruit Tree | A | Short Trees | 005 | 2020 | Living | 12 | 3 |
| Sunrise | 1 | Fruit Tree | B | Vines | 001 | 2022 | Living | 12 | 3 |
| Sunrise | 1 | Fruit Tree | B | Vines | 002 | 2019 | Dead | 12 | 3 |
| Sunrise | 1 | Fruit Tree | B | Vines | 003 | 2021 | Living | 12 | 3 |
| Beauty | 1 | Fruit Tree | B | Vines | 004 | 2020 | Dead | 12 | 3 |
| Beauty | 1 | Fruit Tree | B | Vines | 005 | 2020 | Living | 12 | 3 |
| Green.5 | 1 | Fruit Tree | C | Tall Trees | 001 | 2019 | Living | 12 | 3 |
| Green.4 | 1 | Fruit Tree | C | Tall Trees | 002 | 2019 | Unplanted | 12 | 3 |
| Green.3 | 1 | Fruit Tree | C | Tall Trees | 003 | 2022 | Unplanted | 12 | 3 |
| Green.2 | 1 | Fruit Tree | C | Tall Trees | 004 | 2021 | Living | 12 | 3 |
| Green.1 | 1 | Fruit Tree | C | Tall Trees | 005 | 2022 | Unplanted | 12 | 3 |
| Big Leaf | 1 | Fruit Tree | D | Shrubs | 001 | 2019 | Unplanted | 12 | 3 |
| Big leaf | 1 | Fruit Tree | D | Shrubs | 002 | 2019 | Unplanted | 12 | 3 |
| Yellow Trumpit | 1 | Fruit Tree | D | Shrubs | 003 | 2022 | Dead | 12 | 3 |
| Orange Trumpit | 1 | Fruit Tree | D | Shrubs | 004 | 2021 | Living | 12 | 3 |
| Blue Bells | 1 | Fruit Tree | D | Shrubs | 005 | 2020 | Unplanted | 12 | 3 |

### Example Output Data

[Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chvwC.png)

Comment: These questions where helpful, and similar to mine in some ways, but I was not able to answer my question with them.
[Transforming ugly survey data in Excel / Power Query](https://superuser.com/questions/1682969/transforming-ugly-survey-data-in-excel-power-query)
[Make columns into row subgroups in Pivot Table](https://superuser.com/questions/1732006/make-columns-into-row-subgroups-in-pivot-table)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Variety", type text}, {"Block", Int64.Type}, {"BlockNm", type text}, {"RowN", type text}, {"RowNm", type text}, {"Loc", Int64.Type}, {"Planting Year", type text}, {"Status", type text}, {"RowSp", Int64.Type}, {"LocSp", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "dataName", each [Variety] &" - "&[Planting Year]),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "colName", each [RowN]&": "&[RowNm]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Variety", "Block", "BlockNm", "RowN", "RowNm", "Planting Year", "Status", "RowSp", "LocSp"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[colName]), "colName", "dataName"),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Loc", "D: Shrubs", "C: Tall Trees", "B: Vines", "A: Short Trees"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

All of these can can be done with ribbon commands; here is the output:
[image]

The steps are:

- source: original table
- Changed Type: auto change type, but I changed the date to text
- Added Custom: join columns Variety & Year
- Added Custom1: join columns rowN & rowNm
- Removed Columns: remove all columns except (Loc and 2 created custom columns)
- Pivoted Column: make rowN/rowNm columsn with Variety/year as data (advance don't aggregate)
- reorder columns to get into your column order

Getting this into the final format in Excel may be problematic. I don't want to make you go down another (potentially unprofitable) path, but added with your other ask you may need to consider some type of BI Analysis tool (power BI, Tableau, etc).

Comment: This was a great exercise in understanding more about Power Query and its possible limitations. I will look more into Power BI for my asks relating to conditional formatting.

Comment: I would say power BI is more the actual presentation. Power Query (part of power BI) would be the manipulation to get it into the format for power BI to then grab and present. Good luck.

Comment: Noted and appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I realized a few days after your answer that I can achieve the final formatting part of my question by creating a template in Visio and joining the data from Excel. I know Visio wasn't part of my original question, but if someone finds themselves with a similar situation in the future, it's one potential option to accomplish the task.

Comment: @GNG85, interesting comment. If I have such a use case I'll give it a try.